# Tinting action bar icons with AppCompact v7 on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

Is there an easy way of tinting the drawer icon, overflow menu icon and all action bar icons with a single theme color or do we need to color each icon separately. As mentioned in the title we are using Actionbar with support library compat v7 with SDK 21.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this solution works for ActionBar icons, should be valid for AppCompat too

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem favoriteItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_favorite);
    Drawable newIcon = (Drawable)favoriteItem.getIcon();
    newIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.myCustomTint), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    favoriteItem.setIcon(newIcon);
    return true;
}
```

More info on this question: [Tint menu icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301235/tint-menu-icons)

Comment: Excellent, worked for me on API lv 22 (5.1). Would like to add for noobs like me that the above code is added to the 'onCreateOptionsMenu()' method after the 'getMenuInflater().inflate()' method has been called. Also, remember to add a colors.xml resource and define some colors to use for your tints.