# How To Change Color Of Drawable PNG Item in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I have this xml code :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_id"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent">
    </bitmap>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/shoppingcart_id"
    android:title="Shopping Cart"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
```

they both are black icons but the first icon I want to change into red. but when I run my app, it doesn't show anything. Is it possible to change PNG file color from drawable resource just using XML without adding code in java?

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tint menu icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301235/tint-menu-icons)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

*Woops, just realized you were talking about a menu icon, so, just try wrapping your bitmap in a drawable file, like explained in here:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535399/7296930

---

The solution depends on your API version.

**For API 21+:**

Just try defining the icon as another drawable with a tint, and reference this new drawable as the icon (instead of the < bitmap > tag) ?

**For API<21:**

Juste follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095222/android-imageview-change-tint-to-simulate-button-click/18724834#18724834), using a custom TintableImageView and custom attribute.
You will have to code some Java to define the TintableImageView widget, but then your drawable will be defined only in xml, with something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.widgets.TintableImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        app:tint="@color/color_selector"/>

</LinearLayout>
```